# Join string with html entities in javascript and display as HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In angular controller file, I want to add suffix *...* to make shorten a string if it is lengthy but now `...` is now a spread operator in es6 so try using `&hellip;`  and tried but it prints the text `&hellip;` not *...* in HTML

trial 1

```
let shortName = `${longString.substr(0,9)}${(longString.length>9? '&hellip;':'';`
```

trial 2

```
$sce.trustAsHtml(shortName + '&hellip;')
```

but in HTML it show `&hellp;` not the *...*

Note:  I can use `ng-bind-html` but this string is used as a label in chart which is in `<canvas>` and that is created by the angular-chrat.js library.

I do not want to manipulate it through library but using core Javascipt.

Comment: Why not using its utf8 equivalent?

Comment: and what it will be? Please suggest how to do

Comment: I mentioned that in my answer. Also a triple dot should work fine too, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes but my question is how to use html entities . this is specific to `&hellip;` suppose I want to use `&copy;` than?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the utf-8 equivalent character if you have set your charset to utf-8: `'…'`

You mentioned you are using it in canvas? If so you have to convert your entity into a symbol instead. You can use a DOMParser for that.
[Here is a way to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/881032)

Comment: yes I can use but I want to know how to use html entities in javascript.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, this is working fine but still checking does angular have the solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by checking?

Comment: I means looking for angularJS solution also.yes this is working and I have accepted the answer.

Comment: I think the angular version would be to use `ng-bind-html`. Even with $sce, you kinda need to use `ng-bind-html`

Comment: I am try using `.filter` but it change the string into array

Comment: Yes, [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is used to filter elements inside an array and a string is kinda a represantation of a character array. You could use [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) though - but all of that is pure javascript

Comment: created as angular [filter](https://gist.github.com/zymr-keshav/2377d5d46dafde1e2c474b60152c4696). Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ng-bind-html`? [Click here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) to check documentation

Comment: I can not do that in HTML, this text is being used as a label  in graph which is in `<canvas>`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `HTML entities` before cancating into string

```
let e = document.createElement('div');
e.innerHTML = '&hellip;';

let shortName = `${longString.substr(0,9)}${(longString.length>9? ${e.innerText}:'';`
```

or can use `DOMParser`

```
let p = new DOMParser();
let d = p.parseFromString('&hellip;', 'text/html');
let shortName = `${longString.substr(0,9)}${(longString.length>9? ${d.documentElement.textContent}:'';`
```

Comment: I dont want to put this string in any other HTML element such as `div` you suggested

Comment: and `innerText` or `innerHTML`  in last line? I think there is typo

Comment: That is not typo. we just need the symbol, so it is obtained by `innerText`

Comment: @pro.mean `entity` can't be used without `parsing` it